# Fetch values from mysql database between year_1 and year_2

Tags: mysql, select, fetch

Actually I want user to select two years and then I want to fetch those rows from the mysql database which come in between these selected years.
For example user select year_1= 2006  and year_2= 2009 Then I want to display all the records between year 2006 and 2009
I guess Code will make it easier to understand

```
$year_1='2006';
$year_2='2009';    
$sql= "Select names FROM persons WHERE year_1 >= $year_1 and year_1 <= $year_2;
```

This query is selecting only the names in $year_1 and $year_2 (year 2006 and 2009) but not those in 2007 and 2008;
I want to select 2007 and 2008 names also. Tell me how to modify this code?

Comment: Q: It looks like you have two separate columns (year_1 and year_2) on the persons table, and you are intending to check both. Is that correct?  Q: If row has year_1=2006 and year_2=2012, should that record be returned or not? If row has year_1=2004 and year_2=2012, should that row be returned?  (The query needed to satisfy the specification really depends on what is specified. The query in the (very) good answer from Zane Bien satisfies one interpretation of the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
$sql= "SELECT *
  FROM names
  WHERE year_1 BETWEEN $year_1 AND $year_2";
```

Comment: I guess you got the point. Let me check this query.
Isn't it selecting the all values of year_1 which comes between $year_1 and $year_2 ?

Comment: The code you provided first worked perfectly. I have one column actually year_1 and no year_2 so the conclusion goes here
`$sql="SELECT * FROM names WHERE year_1 BETWEEN $year_1 and $year_2"`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM names
 WHERE (year_1 BETWEEN $year_1 AND $year_2) AND
       (year_2 BETWEEN $year_1 AND $year_2)
```

---

Assuming this is how you want to filter it, suppose $year_1 = 2006 and $year_2 = 2009, the filter would look something like:

```
-- 2006 <-----y1-------------------------y2--> 2009     >> Row returned
-- 2006/y1 <---------------------------------> 2009/y2  >> Row returned
-- <----y1-------2006-------------------y2---> 2009     >> Row filtered out
-- 2006 <---------------y1------2009-----y2-->          >> Row filtered out
-- <-----y1-----------y2------2006-----2009-->          >> Row filtered out
-- <--2006-----2009--------y1-----------y2--->          >> Row filtered out
```

So only if the ***range*** of `year_1` to `year_2` falls ***between*** or ***on*** the input years, the row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is that you have only a single "year" column in your table. (We may be mistakenly implying (from the references to "year_1" and "year_2" in your question) that your table has two separate "year" columns you are wanting to check.)

If you have only one "year" column that you are checking, then it's pretty simple query:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM persons p
 WHERE p.year >= $year_1 AND p.year <= $year_2
```

But your question seems to reference two separate columns: year_1 and year_2, in addition to your two variables $year_1 and $year_2.

So, another possible interpretation of the spec is that the year_1 and year_2 columns are lower and upper bounds of a continuous range, and you want to find rows that satisfy an entire given range of years.

As an example, year_1 might be "birth year" and year_2 might be "death year", and I am wanting to find all rows from the persons table who were "alive" EVERY year in a given range:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM persons p
 WHERE p.year_1 <= $year_1 
   AND p.year_2 >= $year_2
```

(I don't think this is what you're asking, but I'm not sure.)

Another possible interpretation is that I want to find anyone that was "alive" during ANY (but not necessarily all) years in a given range. I'd get that with a query like:

```
 SELECT p.*
   FROM persons p
  WHERE p.year_1 <= $year_2
     OR p.year_2 >= $year_1
```

Or, I may be asking a fundamentally different question, looking for an event year during particular range of years.

Like I want to find anyone that was either "born" or that "died" in a given range of years...

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM persons p
   WHERE p.year_1 >= $year_1 AND p.year_1 <= $year_2
      OR p.year_2 >= $year_1 AND p.year_2 <= $year_2
```

But again, it's not clear from your question which (if any) of those result sets you actually want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$year_1 = '2006';
$year_2 = '2009';
$sql = "SELECT names FROM persons WHERE year_1 >= $year_1 AND year_2 <= $year_2";
```